# Random playlist video not working. Help. JS Fiddle available

Tags: javascript, video, random, playlist

I'm trying to make the playlist random. It seems like something is wrong. The first video plays fine but next one won't play.

This is where the fiddle is located:
https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielluz/hwaLxjh8/

```
<video id="w-video" class="video-js w-video" muted autoplay width=640 height=480>   

</video>
<ul id="playlist">
<li><a href="http://www.pipanimation.com/w3/media/Videos/videos/aapiprdemor2015rfinal.mp4">Number One</a>
<li><a href="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4">Number Two</a>
<li><a href="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-Death_Becomes_Fur.mp4">Number Three</a>
</ul>

// Get the playlist from the available URLs on the list 
    playlist = $('#playlist');
    tracks = playlist.find('li a');
    len = tracks.length - 1;
// Select a random item from the list...
    vid = Math.round(Math.random()*len);
// ... and get the href
    vidURL = tracks[vid].href;

//console.log(vid + " " + vidURL)
// Set the source to the selected URL
    $("#w-video").get(0).src = vidURL
// Play the selected URL
    $("#w-video").get(0).play();
```

Comment: Clicking on the link will just open a new page

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing content, you're trying to load http videos in a https page (JSfiddle uses https)

EDIT: I tried with jsfiddle and http and it seems to work

EDIT2: You have no function to play the next video when the first one ends, thats the problem, try to use something like that:

```
var video = document.getElementByID('w-video');

video.onended = function(e) {
  //function to play the next video
};
```

EDIT3:

> Do I insert this text into the end of the script?

You should take another approach, try something like:

```
function shuffle (array) {
  var i = 0
    , j = 0
    , temp = null

  for (i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i -= 1) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1))
    temp = array[i]
    array[i] = array[j]
    array[j] = temp
  }
}

function play_vid() {
    video.src = links[current]
    video.play();
    if(current!=links.length) {
        current++;
    }
}

var video = $("#w-video").get(0);
var current = 0;
var links = [];
playlist = $('#playlist');
tracks = playlist.find('li a');

$.each(tracks, function(){
    links.push($(this).attr('href'));
});
shuffle(links);
play_vid();


video.onended = function(e) {
    play_vid();
};
```

Working version on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hwaLxjh8/2/

Comment: Do I insert this text into the end of the script?

Comment: @FranM.W. See my 3rd EDIT